# Choosing a panel regression model in R

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, panel-data, plm

I am trying to work out how to use panel regression in R and am not sure on whether to use FE, RE, pooling or between models

Hello,

I am new to panel regression and trying to get my head around it. Im currently using a model to predict total annual returns of funds, which include continuous, categorical and interaction terms. My indexes are the funds ID and the year, and the categorical variables are dummies for each level (with 1 dummy not included). As I want to include time-invariant variables (the dummies) I have set up the fixed effect model with effects = "time" as R no longer drops these, but have read that using model="pooling" is also an appropriate way to use time-invariant variables. I have also set up a random and "between" model, as these allow me to keep them in. The "between" model has very high adjusted R2, but there seems to be really little out there about what this model estimator means, and whether it's the correct approach to use. Basically, I have been trying to read everything I can to work out the best approach to take and there seem to be lots of different approaches so my head is spinning slightly! Any insight into how I can judge the best model to use/ whether I'm really barking up the wrong tree would be much appreciated.

fixed effects model (use model="within")
Europewithin <- plm(TotalReturnAnnual~ UKDummy+ GermanyDummy + NetherlandsDummy + FranceDummy + ItalyDummy + FinlandDummy + Residential + IndustrialLogistics + Multi.Sector + Office + Retail + CoreClosedEnd+ GAV + I(GAV^2)+ Age + I(Age^2)+ gearingLag + I(gearingLag^2)+ InterestRate +CPIGrowth + BBBBonds + InflationSurprise + M1MoneySupply + InterestRate + Dummy2009Onwards+ GermanyDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + UKDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + UKDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + NetherlandsDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + NetherlandsDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + GermanyDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + GermanyDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + FranceDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + FranceDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + ItalyDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + ItalyDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + ItalyDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + FinlandDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + FinlandDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + gearingLag:CoreDummy + I(gearingLag^2):CoreDummy + BrentCrude + RealGDPGrowth + CPIGrowth:InflationSurprise + RealGDPGrowth:InflationSurprise +gearingLag:UpmarketDummy + gearingLag:DownMarketDummy , data=panel, model="within", index = c("FundID", "Year"), effect="time")

pooling model
Europepool <- plm(TotalReturnAnnual~ UKDummy+ GermanyDummy + NetherlandsDummy + FranceDummy + ItalyDummy + FinlandDummy + Residential + IndustrialLogistics + Multi.Sector + Office + Retail + CoreClosedEnd+ GAV + I(GAV^2)+ Age + I(Age^2)+ gearingLag + I(gearingLag^2)+ InterestRate +CPIGrowth + BBBBonds + InflationSurprise + M1MoneySupply + InterestRate + Dummy2009Onwards+ GermanyDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + UKDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + UKDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + NetherlandsDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + NetherlandsDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + GermanyDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + GermanyDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + FranceDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + FranceDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + ItalyDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + ItalyDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + ItalyDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + FinlandDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + FinlandDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + gearingLag:CoreDummy + I(gearingLag^2):CoreDummy + BrentCrude + RealGDPGrowth + CPIGrowth:InflationSurprise + RealGDPGrowth:InflationSurprise +gearingLag:UpmarketDummy + gearingLag:DownMarketDummy , data=panel, model="pooling", index = c("FundID", "Year"))

betweenmodel <- plm(TotalReturnAnnual~ UKDummy+ GermanyDummy + NetherlandsDummy + FranceDummy + ItalyDummy + FinlandDummy + Residential + IndustrialLogistics + Multi.Sector + Office + Retail + CoreClosedEnd+ GAV + I(GAV^2)+ Age + I(Age^2)+ gearingLag + I(gearingLag^2)+ InterestRate +CPIGrowth + BBBBonds + InflationSurprise + M1MoneySupply + InterestRate + Dummy2009Onwards+ GermanyDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + UKDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + UKDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + NetherlandsDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + NetherlandsDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + GermanyDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + GermanyDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + FranceDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + FranceDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + ItalyDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + ItalyDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + ItalyDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + FinlandDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + FinlandDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + gearingLag:CoreDummy + I(gearingLag^2):CoreDummy + BrentCrude + RealGDPGrowth + CPIGrowth:InflationSurprise + RealGDPGrowth:InflationSurprise +gearingLag:UpmarketDummy + gearingLag:DownMarketDummy, data=panel, model="between", index = c("FundID", "Year"))

random model
Europerandom <- plm(TotalReturnAnnual~ UKDummy+ GermanyDummy + NetherlandsDummy + FranceDummy + ItalyDummy + FinlandDummy + Residential + IndustrialLogistics + Multi.Sector + Office + Retail + CoreClosedEnd+ GAV + I(GAV^2)+ Age + I(Age^2)+ gearingLag + I(gearingLag^2)+ InterestRate +CPIGrowth + BBBBonds + InflationSurprise + M1MoneySupply + InterestRate + Dummy2009Onwards+ GermanyDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + UKDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + UKDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + NetherlandsDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + NetherlandsDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + GermanyDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + GermanyDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + FranceDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + FranceDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + ItalyDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + ItalyDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + ItalyDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + FinlandDummy:Dummy2007_2008 + FinlandDummy:Dummy2009Onwards + gearingLag:CoreDummy + I(gearingLag^2):CoreDummy + BrentCrude + RealGDPGrowth + CPIGrowth:InflationSurprise + RealGDPGrowth:InflationSurprise +gearingLag:UpmarketDummy + gearingLag:DownMarketDummy , data=panel, model="random", index = c("FundID", "Year"))

I would like to be able to confidently justify the correct approach to use, apologies for the lack of data, it's not possible for me to share it.

Comment: How many funds do you have and how many years ?

Comment: Hi, @RobertLong I think its 545 funds over a 19 year period, but the panel data set is unbalanced

Comment: Hi @RobertLong theres 545 funds, over a 19 year period, and the dataset is unbalanced